# How to answer this kind of questions

Tags: radicals

How can I answer this kind of questions?

I should prove the following

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_1} + \sqrt{a_2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_2} + \sqrt{a_3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_3} + \sqrt{a_4}} + ... + \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{n-1}} + \sqrt{a_n}} = \frac{n-1}{\sqrt{a_1} + \sqrt{a_n}}$$

[image]

Sorry for my poor English

Comment: I see only one "phrase" there

Comment: Sorry I edited the picture and it removed , I will replace it

Comment: No problem.  For the future, there [here is an explanation](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) of how to type math on this website.

Comment: That's n-1 at the top

Comment: Is there a rule for the $a_n$?  This isn't true in general for any sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$.  For instance $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{9}} \not= \frac{2}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{9}}$.

Comment: I'm assuming the $a_i$ form an arithmetic sequence, based on the proposition?

Comment: I think $a_i$ form an arithmetic progression too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\sqrt{a_1}-\sqrt{a_2}}{{a_1} + {a_2}}+\frac{\sqrt{a_2}-\sqrt{a_3}}{{a_2}-{a_3}}+....+\frac{\sqrt{a_{n-1}}-\sqrt{a_n}}{a_{n-1}-{a_n}}=\frac{\sqrt{a_1}-\sqrt{a_2}}{-d}+\frac{\sqrt{a_2}-\sqrt{a_3}}{-d}+....+\frac{\sqrt{a_{n-1}}-\sqrt{a_n}}{-d}=\frac{\sqrt{a_1}-\sqrt{a_2}+\sqrt{a_2}-\sqrt{a_3}+....+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}-\sqrt{a_n}}{-d}=\frac{\sqrt{a_1}-\sqrt{a_n}}{-d}=\frac{\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{a_1}}{-d}\times\frac{\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{a_1}}{\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{a_1}}=\frac{a_n-a_1}{d(\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{a_1})}=\frac{(n-1)d}{d(\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{a_1})}=\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{a_1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $a_i = a_1+(i-1)\delta$ for all $i > 0$ and some $\delta$.  Proceed by induction.  Let

$$
S_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_1}+\sqrt{a_2}}+
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_2}+\sqrt{a_3}}+\cdots+
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_{k-1}}+\sqrt{a_k}}
$$

Observe that for $k = 2$, we have

$$
S_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_1}+\sqrt{a_2}}
$$

trivially.  Next, suppose that

$$
S_k = \frac{k-1}{\sqrt{a_1}+\sqrt{a_k}}
$$

Then, keeping in mind that $a_k = a_1+(k-1)\delta$,

\begin{align}
S_{k+1}
    & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_1}+\sqrt{a_2}}+
        \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_2}+\sqrt{a_3}}+\cdots+
        \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_k}+\sqrt{a_{k+1}}} \\
    & = \frac{k-1}{\sqrt{a_1}+\sqrt{a_k}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_k}+\sqrt{a_{k+1}}} \\
    & = \frac{k-1}{\sqrt{a_1}+\sqrt{a_1+(k-1)\delta}}
      + \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_k}+\sqrt{a_k+\delta}} \\
    & = \frac{(k-1)(\sqrt{a_1+(k-1)\delta}-\sqrt{a_1})}{(k-1)\delta}
      + \frac{\sqrt{a_k+\delta}-\sqrt{a_k}}{\delta} \\
    & = \frac{\sqrt{a_k}-\sqrt{a_1}}{\delta}
      + \frac{\sqrt{a_{k+1}}-\sqrt{a_k}}{\delta} \\
    & = \frac{\sqrt{a_{k+1}}-\sqrt{a_1}}{\delta} \\
    & = \frac{\sqrt{a_1+k\delta}-\sqrt{a_1}}{\delta} \\
    & = \frac{k\delta}{\delta(\sqrt{a_1+k\delta}+\sqrt{a_1})} \\
    & = \frac{k}{\sqrt{a_1}+\sqrt{a_{k+1}}}
\end{align}

For instance,

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{25}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{25}+\sqrt{49}}
    & = \frac{1}{1+5}+\frac{1}{5+7} \\
    & = \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{12} \\
    & = \frac{3}{12} \\
    & = \frac{2}{8} \\
    & = \frac{3-1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{49}}
\end{align}